# The area of a certain region

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $a,b,c,d$ be real numbers such that $\det \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \ne 0$. Let $X$ be a large positive parameter; one should think of $X \rightarrow \infty$.

Define

$$\displaystyle A_{a,b,c,d}(X) = \text{Area} \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \left \lvert (ax + by)(cx+dy)(x^2 + y^2)^2\right \rvert \leq X, |ax+by| \geq 1, |cx+dy| \geq 1 \}.$$

Note that the region above is compact, but still somewhat skew.

My question is: how to express $A_{a,b,c,d}(X)$ as an asymptotic formula, with the main term given by well-known functions?